# how to access the Menu's which is placed in the action Bar(in Android Phones) in Robotium

Tags: android, for-loop, android-actionbar, robotium

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| **Menu1**|**Menu2**|**Menu3**                |
|----------------------------------------------|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              | 
|                                              |
-----------------------------------------------|                                              |
```

Tried with all the options such clickOnImage, ClickonImageButton,ClickonMenu, ClickonMenuItem,ClickonText etc.. but none of the methods work.. please let me know the way to access the Menu placed in the ActionBar...

Comment: Are these menus defined in the menu.xml? Do you support older phones with ActionbarSherlock?

Comment: Those are not exactly the Action Bars, those are Menu's with Images placed on the Top Header of the Home Screen in the APP.

Comment: Those are not defined in the Menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(mActivity, R.id.menu_item_id, 0);
```